# Unable to install Test Manager extension on Azure DevOps Server 2019

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, azure-devops-server-2019

Recently we have upgraded our TFS server to the latest 2019 version.

As the Admin, I was trying to install the downloaded **Test Manager** extension just like we did in TFS2017 and TFS2018.

However, I was unable to install it even with full access and TFS test plan subscription.

> This extension does not support the version of the Server you are
>   currently using. See Works With for supported Server versions.

What should I do, am I missing something? Why it not work with TFS2019? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior when you try to install the extension in Azure DevOps Server 2019. **You do not need to install extra Test Manger for Azure DevOps Server 2019.**

The official [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web&ssr=false#overview)  is also  clearly: *This extension does not support the version of the Server you are currently using. See Works With for supported Server versions.*

It only work Works with

- Team Foundation Server 2017
- Team Foundation Server 2018

**Note:**

1. Manual testers do not need this extension and can execute tests as a
       Basic user in an Azure DevOps organization/collection. Read more on
       this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=azure-devops#license-requirements).
2. This extension is available out-of-the-box in Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps Server (2019 onwards) and hence doesn't need to be acquired for them.

We strongly recommend you to use Azure Test Plans or the Test hub in Azure DevOps Service/Server (a fully featured Test management solution) over Microsoft Test Manager for all your test management requirements. There will be no new versions of Microsoft Test Manager.Microsoft Test Manager 2017 (which shipped with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017) is the last version.

More details please take a look at our official tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/mtm/guidance-mtm-usage?view=azure-devops).

---

Besides, to use Azure Test Plans in Azure DevOps service you need some License requirements

Azure Test Plans uses an access level called Basic + Test Plans, which is available from Azure DevOps.

[image]

For the Manual testing permissions and access suggest refer this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=azure-devops#license-requirements

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentiond in the [Extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web):

> This extension is available out-of-the-box in Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps Server (2019 onwards) and hence doesn't need to be acquired for them.

So you don't to install it, it's exist :) just go to the "Test Pans" tab in the left menu (maybe you need give permissions in the settings).